# Using a switch statement instead of multiple IF's

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Hi I have the below code and wanted to know the best way to replace it using a switch statement.This example I have 4 possible outcomes but I might end up with over 20 and if statements would get to cluttered .

```
$Des = "C:\tools\"
$DListFiles = Get-ChildItem $Des -EA 0

IF((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles -eq $null){$DDE = 1}
ElseIF((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles -ne $null){$DDE = 2}
ElseIF((Test-Path $Des)-eq $false){$DDE = 3}
Else{$DDE = 4}

write-host "$DDE"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring some thing out that would work let me know what you all think.

```
$Des = "c:\test\"
$DListFiles = Get-ChildItem $Des -EA 0

Switch($Des)
   {  {!$Des} {$DDE = 4; break}
      {((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles -eq $null)}  {$DDE = 1; break}
      {((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles -ne $null)}  {$DDE = 2; break}
      {((Test-Path $Des)-eq $false)}                             {$DDE = 3; break}
   }

 $DDE
```

Answer (score 4):

For the example that you posted, personally I would use a nested if to make the logic clearer:

```
If(Test-Path $Des){
    If($DListFiles -eq $null){
        $DDE = 1
    }Else{
        $DDE = 2
    }
}Else{
    If($DListFiles -eq $null){
        $DDE = 3
    }else{
        $DDE = 4
    }
}
```

By the way, the way that you have it written does not give the logic that I think that you want. I don't believe you would ever get $DDE = 2. If I'm reading what you posted correctly, the logic table is posted below. Again, a Nested If would help sort it out.

```
Test-Path   $Dlist is Null      $DDE
TRUE            TRUE            1
FALSE           FALSE           3
TRUE            TRUE            4
FALSE           FALSE           3
```

Comment: Ye I had the same problem with nested IF statements if gets complex and  hard to figure out the state.

Comment: For just 4 states it isn't too bad. You said something about 20 possibilities in your question. In that case, a switch probably would be right, but you did not explain that any further. So for 4 states I would say that If-Then is right.

Comment: Ye there will be about 20 possible and very different states did not want to put a big example hear as it would be hard to follow and if i got an example with 4 it would be easy to change it. Also from my code you can see i evaluate multiple thing to determine each state for example ((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles -ne $null should be state 2 but ((Test-Path $Des)-ne $false -and $DListFiles --eq $null should be state 1

Comment: In general, if you have one parameter that can be in multiple possible states, then a switch is best. If you have multiple paramters that can be in multiple states, as you noticed the logic becomes complexe. In that case some logic structure other than a switch will probably be best. Actually if you have many parameters and each parameter has only two states, then personally I would look at using a bit mask to determine the overall state then switch based on that.

Comment: Do you have a link to an article or an example of a bit mask ?

Comment: I have not needed to fully work out using a bitmask in powershell yet for myself, but there is a discussion of the bitwise comparison operators here http://www.sapien.com/forums/scriptinganswers/forum_posts.asp?TID=1846 that would be a good start